# What is the meaning of "a trouvaille, mon cher"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, literature, french

I was reading *A Model Millionaire* by Oscar Wilde and came across this line. Can someone explain it to me?

> "An amazing model?' shouted Jain at the top of his voice; 'I should
>   think so! Such beggars as he are not to be met with every day. A
>   trouvaille, mon cher; a living Velasquez! My stars! what an etching
>   Rembrandt would have made of him!'

Comment: It's French, not English :) Literally, _a dead find, dear_.

Comment: i tried google translate but it was really confusing, i know it's irrelevant but could you please provide me the literal translation of some other phrases?

Comment: @oerkelens It's French words, but the sequence of words is meaningless. *A* is a form of the verb *be*; if we posit that an accent got lost in transcription, *à* is a preposition which typically translates to *to* (but of course the translation of such prepositions is highly context-sensitive). Also, in order for the adjective *mort* to qualify *trouvaille*, it should be spelled and pronounced *morte*. And *cher* in such a vocative use should be *mon cher*. As written, this is not intelligible French. Lucyfer, can you give a bit more context?

Comment: Are you sure it's written like that? "Une trouvaille, mon cher" would be correct ("What a find, my dear/friend"). As you've written it, it is meaningless as Gilles said.

Comment: @Gilles - _a_ would be a form of the verb _have_ in French, not _be_. But I am quite sure that _a_ here is actually the only _English_ word in the whole phrase, and is is nothing but the _indefinite article_. Just like people will say they have **a** deja-vu. As for the grammatical concord between _trouvaille_ and _mort(e)_, you are right — providing that Wilde intended to be grammatically correct. The use of _deja-vu_, missing its accents and all, shows a bit of the care English takes of French grammar when borrowing from that language.

Comment: @oerkelens Oops, yes, *have*, not *be*. And yes, it's the English article. As for *mort*, it turns out to be a transcription error (either a printer's error or an OCR error, I haven't tracked it down): other editions have *mon*.

Comment: It is very likely to be an OCR error. A bit of a broken _n_ gets read as _rt_ more often, as I have experienced...

Comment: i's just a typo, for goodness sake. "trouvaille" simply means "find" - really, it's that simple.  if you've "found your glasses" you yell out "trouve!"  there's nothing to it, just check trouvaille in even google translate

Comment: sorry trouvé for the record (screw accents! :) )

Comment: General Reference [**trouvaille**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trouvaille) *:  a lucky find :  windfall.* French, from Old French *trouver* to compose, find.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about the English language.

Comment: Edwin - nah man, it's a loan-word issue. and posh-french-usage-in-literature is a completely normal part of english; the issues surrounding that are at home here.  (plus any famous author gets a pass and can't be off topic here :) )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us see [a bit more context](http://books.google.fr/books?id=SUSkAQAAQBAJ&pg=PT166&lpg=PT166&dq=%22a+trouvaille+mort,+cher). This is a line in a dialogue between two characters in the novel. [Other editions](http://books.google.fr/books?id=peORKhTxKlgC&pg=PT378&lpg=PT378&dq=%22a+trouvaille+mon+cher) spell it differently (I'm only reproducing the relevant excerpt):

> — What an amazing model!
>   — An amazing model? I should think so! Such beggars as he are not to be met with every day. **A *trouvaille*, *mon cher***; a living Velazquez!

The French word *mort* (meaning death) doesn't make any sense in this context, whereas the French phrase “*mon cher*”, meaning “my dear” would be expected in this context (*cher* alone is not idiomatic French). Thus the correct phrase is obviously “*mon cher*”. This is obviously a transcription error where `rt` was misread as `n` — either a printer's error or an OCR error in the edition you're reading. As for the position of the comma, I couldn't find a source other than you that had a comma before *cher* instead of after *trouvaille*.

*Trouvaille* means something that has been found, with an emphatic, positive connotation: a great find, a remarkable find, an interesting find, an exceptional find. This can be something that is discovered experimentally or something that is invented. As for *a*, it's the English indeterminate article.

Comment: @oerkelens Better? (I have no idea what your point 1 means: why would I cite another, unrelated text?)

Comment: it's 1000% a typo.  totally certain.

Comment: +1 for the searching and recognizing the (probably) OCR mistake.

Answer (score 0):

As **Mat** said, I wonder why he did not write an answer, the original text is:

> Such beggars as he are not to be met with every day. A **trouvaille**,
>   mon cher; ... My stars!

'trouvaille' is a windfall, a treasure trove, the pot at the end of the rainbow.

"*a treasure trove, my dear!... I thank my lucky stars!*/ what a luck/ I was so lucky!.

@PeterShor,
the definition (Larousse):*"Fait de trouver... quelque chose d'extraordinaire.."*
The usual translations 'find','windfall', 'lucky find' do not fully render the fact that it is something extraordinary. I chose 'treasure trove', if you read the story probably will agree it fits the context better than other transltions.

Comment: Both in French and in English, a [*"trouvaille"*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/trouvaille) is a *find*, usually an exceptional one, but not necessarily a [*treasure trove*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/treasure-trove?q=treasure+trove). (Of course, a *treasure trove* is a specific kind of *find*, but *trouvaille* is more general.)

Answer (score 0):

it simply means "a find!" (by implication, "a nice find!" or "what a find!")

i's that simple.

Yes, it's a typo.  it's just "A trouvaille, mon cher"

BTW that word is pronounced like "troo-vie" (rhymes with "eye")